# Unbound local error in object

Tags: python, object

I am running code querying a modem, when the modem comes up I have set these variables in my object init to periodically measure signal strength:

```
self.rssi_sleep_time = 60
self.rssi_elapsed_time = 0
```

I then have a thread periodically running some code which will use these values:

```
# Periodically check signal strength.
# When initialised self.rssi_elapsed_time == 0 so this if happens.
if self.rssi_elapsed_time == 0:
    start_time = time.time()
self.rssi_elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
if self.rssi_elapsed_time > self.rssi_sleep_time:
    <do stuff>
    self.rssi_elapsed_time = 0
```

So at a minimum interval of 60 seconds the code will run and the timer reset, this works fine most of the time, however I have noticed that sometimes I am getting this error in my logs, any idea why? Somehow the `if` isn't run?

```
exception <type 'exceptions.UnboundLocalError'> in run loop [('logging_timer.py', 197, 'log_mgr', 'self.rssi_elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time')]
```

Comment: Have you declared the start_time before the if statement?

Comment: i guess self.rssi_elapsed_time is True.....so there is no start_time variable....whats happend in 'do stuff', i think the reassignment in the end of the second 'if' is not done....so  self.rssi_elapsed_time is not false